# handle_info :DOWN is not called after monitored process dies

Tags: process, elixir, monitor

I am having an issue with `Process.monitor/1`. My initial use case was to monitor Phoenix Channel and do some cleanup after it dies. However, I didn't manage to set it up in Phoenix and decided to test it out with pure GenServers.

So, I have a simple `GenServer` and I want to track when it dies:

```ex
defmodule Temp.Server do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(_), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{})

  def init(args) do
    Temp.Monitor.monitor(self())
    {:ok, args}
  end
end
```

And another GenServer that monitors:

```ex
defmodule Temp.Monitor do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def monitor(pid) do
    Process.monitor(pid)
  end

  def handle_info({:DOWN, ref, :process, _, _}, state) do
    Logger.info("DOWN")

    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

So, if I understand correctly, `Process.monitor` will start monitoring the `Temp.Server` process, and should call the `handle_info` matching `:DOWN` when `Server` process dies. If I try it in `iex`:

```ex
iex> {_, pid} = Temp.Server.start_link([])
{:ok, #PID<0.23068.3>}                    
iex> Process.exit(pid, :kill)             
true
```

I expect `handle_info` being called from `Monitor` module and logging "DOWN", however that doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong? I assume it doesn't work because I call to monitor from Server process `Temp.Monitor.monitor(self())`, but I just can't figure out how else should I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the `Temp.Monitor.monitor/1` method, it's still running in `Temp.Server`'s own process, not `Temp.Monitor`'s. That means the `:DOWN` message is sent to `Temp.Server` when `Temp.Server` dies, which is redundant.

What you want to do is, pass the `pid` of your server process to `Temp.Monitor` and have it call the `Process.Monitor` method from it's own process so it can monitor it. That can only happen from one of the [GenServer callbacks](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#callbacks).

**You can do that by moving your implementation in to [`handle_call/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_call/3) or [`handle_cast/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_cast/2):**

```ex
defmodule Temp.Monitor do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def monitor(pid) do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:monitor, pid})
  end

  def handle_cast({:monitor, pid}, state) do
    Process.monitor(pid)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_info({:DOWN, ref, :process, _, _}, state) do
    Logger.info("DOWN")

    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Now I understand it a little bit more. I didn't think that the API functions I define in GenServer and callbacks would run in different processes(I think I got confused because they are in the same module, so I thought they share the same process or smth).

Comment: What if I want to make use of both `terminate` callback and `handle_info :DOWN`. Is it guaranteed that the latter will be always called last, after the terminate callback?

Comment: I'm not sure about the order, but you should keep their logic decoupled anyways.